# Use XPath or onClick or onblur to select an element and use jQuery to blur this element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xpath

***UPDATE:I am new to `jQuery`, as well as using `XPath`, and I am struggling with getting a proper working solution that will `blur` a dynamically created `HTML element`. I have an `.onblur` `event` hooked up (doesn't work as expected), and have tried using the `$(document.activeElement)`, but my implementation might be incorrect. I would appreciate any help in creating a working solution, that will blur this `element` (`jqInput`) when a user clicks anywhere outside the active `element`. I have added the `HTML` and `jQuery/JavaScript` below.**

**Some ideas I have had:**

(1) Use `XPath` to select a dynamic `HTML element` (`jqInput`), and then use `jQuery's .onClick` method to `blur` a this `element`, when a user clicks anywhere outside of the area of the `XPath` selected `element`.

(2) Use the `$(document.activeElement)` to determine where the `.onblur` should fire:

```
var thisTitle = input0;

var activeElement = $(document.activeElement);

if (thisTitle != activeElement) {
    jqInput.hide();
    _layout.viewHeaderTextInput.inputOnBlurHandler(canvasObj, jqHeaderText, jqInput);
}
```

I am open to all working solutions. And hopefully this will answer someone else's question in the future.

**My challenge: Multiple `elements` are active, and the `.onblur` does not fire. See the image below:**

**NOTE**: The `<input />` field has `focus`, as well as the `<div>` to the left of the (the blue outline). If a user clicks anywhere outside that `<input />`, the `blur` must be applied to that `element`.

**My Code: `jQuery` and `JavaScript`**

**This is a code snippet where the variable jqInput and input0 is created:**

```
var jqInput = null;

if (jqHeaderText.next().hasClass("inline-editable"))
{
    //Use existing input if it already exists 
    jqInput = jqHeaderText.next();
}
else
{
    //Creaet a new editable header text input
    jqInput = $("<input class=\"inline-editable\" type=\"text\"/>").insertAfter(jqHeaderText);
}

var input0 = jqInput.get(0);

//Assign key down event for the input when user preses enter to complete entering of the text
input0.onkeydown = function (e)
{
    if (e.keyCode === 13)
    {
        jqInput.trigger("blur");
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
};
```

**This is my `.onblur` `event`, and my helper `method` to `blur` the `element`:**

```
input0.onblur = function ()
{
    _layout.viewHeaderTextInput.inputOnBlurHandler(canvasObj, jqHeaderText, jqInput);
};

inputOnBlurHandler: function (canvasObj, jqHeaderText, jqInput)
{
    // Hide input textbox 
    jqInput.hide();

    // Store the value in the canvas
    canvasObj.headingText = jqInput.val();

    _layout.updateCanvasControlProperty(canvasObj.instanceid, "Title", canvasObj.headingText, canvasObj.headingText);

    // Show header element
    jqHeaderText.show(); 

    _layout.$propertiesContent.find(".propertyGridEditWrapper").filter(function ()
    {
        return $(this).data("propertyName") === "Title";
    }).find("input[type=text]").val(canvasObj.headingText); // Update the property grid title input element
}
```

**I have tried using the active element, but I don't think the implementation is correct:**

```
var thisTitle = input0;

var activeElement = $(document.activeElement);

if (thisTitle != activeElement) {
    jqInput.hide();
    _layout.viewHeaderTextInput.inputOnBlurHandler(canvasObj, jqHeaderText, jqInput);
}
```

**My HTML code:**

```
<div class="panel-header-c">
        <div class="panel-header-wrapper">
            <div class="panel-header-text" style="display: none;">(Enter View Title)</div><input class="inline-editable" type="text" style="display: block;"><div class="panel-header-controls">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse-vertical" tabindex="0"><span></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I thank you all in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by *size*?

Comment: "I would like to get your input with an idea I have" sounds to me as if that question should be closed, because it is likely to generate opinion based answers. Besides: I think it's a terrible idea, because as you stated, there are much easier and better ways to do it.

Comment: @David I have clarified my question and what I am trying to achieve. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: @Taplar I have updated my question with code and some of the methods I have tried

Comment: @PM77-1 Apologies. I am new to using XPath. I improved on my question